# Tumblr won't show comments, need to edit theme to show them

Tags: tumblr, tumblr-themes

Comments aren't showing up on my Tumblr. What do I have to do to my theme in order for the comments to show on my main blog?

Here's the main code portion of the template around the posts:

```
<div id="posts">
 {block:Posts}
 <div id="space">

 <!-- 
   blocks for: 
     text, answer, link, photo, photoset, 
     quote, chat,audio, video, 
 -->

 {block:PermalinkPage}
 {block:Date}
 <div id="permapage">
   <div style="float: left; width: auto; font-weight: bold;">
     Posted on {DayofMonth} {Month}
   </div>
 {/block:Date}

 {block:NoteCount}
 <div style="float: right; width: auto; font-weight: bold;">
   {NoteCountWithLabel}
 </div>
 {/block:NoteCount}

 {block:Caption}<BR>{Caption}{/block:Caption}</div>
 {/block:PermalinkPage}

 {block:PostNotes}{PostNotes}{/block:PostNotes}

 </div>
 {/block:Posts}

 </div>
```

What do I alter in the theme to allow comments on the main blog?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't look like the theme has any commenting system embedded into it. There is no code for either Disqus or IntenseDebate or Facebook comments.

If you wish to add Disqus comments, here're the [instructions for embedding it in Tumblr](http://disqus.com/admin/tumblr/). Please note that you need a Disqus account first.

Comment: Addition to the other answer: I'd particularly recommend Disqus. Very easy to implement and widely used on Tumblr already.